# Create new database with schema from code

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, database, linq

We are building a new cloud based application for our pre-existing clients that will add/replace functionality to our NaCl program they are all using.  Each client has their own database (schemas are 100% identical to one another), and we must create a new instance of the database on our cloud provider.

The sync process for the data is already figured out, and I've managed to create the databases with relative ease.  The only problem is updating the db schemas to match the "db template" (if you will).  I seem to have run into one problem or another depending on my approach:

If I try to send a script (LINQ-to-SQL) to the sql server via ExecuteCommand() I get a slew of errors from declaring scalar variables, to syntax errors, to certain functions needing to be the first statement in a query batch.  This script, mind you, is the script generated from SSMS.

The only other approach I've thought about was executing the script stored locally on the machine (which I have not actually tried yet), but I read that you cannot run a local script with a variable database name...which is a necessity.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SSMS generated scripts contain `go`.  In SSMS `go` ends a batch, but it is not so with ADO.NET's `ExecuteCommand`.

Split the script on `go`, and send each part separately using `ExecuteCommand()`.

Running the script locally (or remotely) using SSMS should also work.

I'm not sure what you mean with "variable database name".  In ADO.NET you can set the database in the connection string.  In SSMS, you can use `use <dbname>` or the dropdown box in the query toolbar.

Comment: Referring to variable db name: consider the following in a function that takes _lcid and i as parameters: `USE [Database_" + (_lcid + 1) + "_" + (i + 1) + @"]`.  I will take a look at splitting this incredibly enormous script up at the GO statements.  Seems like such a hassle.

Comment: Should be easy to create an array of the sections between `go` by using [`string.Split`](http://www.dotnetperls.com/split)

Comment: this did eventually work after a tireless tussle with apostrophe and quotation convention mismatching.  Suffice it to say the db's get created beautifully now.  Thanks for the help, sorry it took so long to accept the answer I forgot I had posted this until just now.